# third largest and smallest number for pairwise swap of number

Tags: java, random

This is the code for finding 3rd largest and 3rd smallest number.

t=no of test cases

num=user input number

if num  is a single digit number it will print impossible.

if the num is 123 then it should store 123,132,213,231,312,321.

Of these the 3rd from the front is 213 and from back is 231.

The problem of my code is that when i input

123 it gives random number with 112,211,133,311...etc

which i don't want.

I want a 3 digit number containing 1,2 and 3.

if the num is 1234 it should have 4321,2134,3124...**Not** 1143,2211.

The problem method is solve(int num).
In this method i have converted integer num to string num and then stored it in the string treeset which i will again convert it into integer treeset so to find 3rd largest and 3rd smallest number.

iam not sure about primefact method(it gives factorial{length of a number ) whether it has use or not...

```
public class ThirdSmallestLargest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    ThirdSmallestLargest tsl=new ThirdSmallestLargest();
    int t,num;
    t=in.nextInt();
    while(t!=0){
        num=in.nextInt();
        tsl.match(num);
        t--;
    }
}
//---------------------Method for finding zero in a number
private void match(int num) {
    int length=(int) (Math.log10(num)+ 1);
    if(length==1){
        System.out.println("Not possible");
    }
    else{
           String s = String.valueOf(num);
           if (s.indexOf('0')<0){
               solve(num);
           }  
    }
}  
//---------------------method for distinct jumble number
 //NOT DONE CONVERT STRING TREESET TO INTEGER TREESET
private void solve(int num) {
        int length=(int) (Math.log10(num)+ 1);
       TreeSet <String> tsstr=new TreeSet<>();
       Iterator<String> itr=tsstr.iterator();
       //Integer.toString(num);
       char[] chars = Integer.toString(num).toCharArray();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // doesnt work with 666,7979 types of number
       Random random =  new Random();  
       while (tsstr.size() <fact(num)){
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {                                 
       char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
           sb.append(c);

        }           
        String output = sb.toString();
        sb.setLength(0);//set the length of the char

       // String input=sb.toString();
        //System.out.println(output);
       // if(output.contentEquals("1"))
      // tsstr.add(Integer.toString(num));

        tsstr.add(output);   
    }
       System.out.println(tsstr);


}

private int fact(int num) {
    int length=(int) (Math.log10(num)+ 1);
    int i,fact=1;
    for(i=1;i<=length;i++){
       fact=fact*i;
    }
    return fact;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can input (`num`) have duplicate digits, e.g. `1223`?

Comment: yes it can have duplicate number

Comment: You don’t need to declare `itr`, you don’t use it anyway. `fact()` will not give you the number of possible permutations if there are duplicate digits, e.g., if the input is 112. You ought to check for 0 or negative input before taking the logarithm (`log10()`). But really, are think you are best off starting over following some of the guidelines from the answers.

Comment: in the above que there are test case with a range of **no of digits=10^5**
so for these big number how to find 3rd largest and 3rd smallest number in a fast manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **sort** the digits.

Let's say input is `111222333444` after sorting. That is the *lowest* number.

Next number is found by swapping last `3` with first `4`, i.e. `111222334344`. Said another way, you move the last second-highest digit one position to the right. That is the *second-lowest* number.

Now there are two cases:

- If there were more than one of the highest digit (`4`), just to it again, i.e. move the last `3` one more to the right: `111222334434`.
- If there was only one `4`, the `3` is at end and can't move to the right, e.g. `1112223334` → `1112223343`, so we move it back, then move the last third-highest digit (`2`) one position to the right: `1112223343` → `1112223334` → `1112232334`

You've now found the *third lowest* number. To recap:
`111222333444` → `111222334344` → **`111222334434`**
`1112223334` → `1112223343` → **`1112232334`**

You can **skip the middle step**. If there is more than one `4`, move last `3` two positions right. Otherwise, move last `2` one position right.

For *third-highest* number you do the same, except reversed:
`444333222111` → `444333221121` *(last `2` moves two positions right)*
`4443332221` → `4443323221` *(last `3` moves one position right)*

I'll leave it to you to write the code for it.

Comment: Upvoted for being helpful without doing the job for the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions to get you going:

1. Separate your code into the different "functions" you need, like: creating all **permutation** of all possible combinations of your numbers
2. Getting them sorted

In other words: first create a list of all possible numbers; then simply use one of the many ways of getting that list sorted; and then you just decided which "indexes" in that sorted lists are of interst to you.

And: choose better abstractions respectively: don't move "jump" from one level to another. Stick with them.

Meaning: initially, consider your user input to be a **string**, not a number (of course, you then have to check that this string only contains digits).

You see, if you have a string, you can directly ask for its length; no need to call log() to figure the numbers of chars in a string. Then, you can easily fetch the individual digits from your string - and you get an array of characters. Now you can easily create permutations of those characters; building strings. Finally, you turn all strings into ints for sorting.

But the point is: all of the above steps should be their own distinct functions. Built small methods (which all of them are perfect for being tested on their own) ... and then compose your solution out of that.

Comment: If you choose to separate the sorting of the numbers from the generation of them, you may find [Heap’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) useful.